# How do I check if a string is in a list of lists, and return the sublist if it is?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to check whether the variable is in a list of lists, and if it is return the sublist.  I've tried a number of different solutions but none of them work...

My code:

```
addressList = [['JohnSmith', 'NR87TYH', 'PE26RE', '1EnglandRoad', '67'],['JaneSmithe', 'UY34DSF', 'SW147EG', '23SouthDrive', '82'], ['JimmyJones', 'PL20DCH', 'NW33EX', '145EastRidings', '54']]

numPlate = "UY34DSF"

for sublist in addressList:
    if numPlate in sublist:
        print("Ding dong the witch is dead!")
```

I should clarify a few things here.  The "addressList" variable is a CSV file stripped into a list that displays as it is written above.

This, or the other 15 or so different methods of doing this haven't worked but I feel this is the closest as the logic makes sense.  Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

EDIT:  Ok so thanks for the answers it made me double check everything in my code but it's still not working so I have copied it and pasted the entire code below.

'line1' returns the value I want from the file.

'reading2' returns the list of list as it should be.

From this, the iterations that I included with my original question should work fine, but aren't?  Any ideas?

```
import csv

fopen = open("StandardUKReg.txt","r")
line1 = fopen.readline()
fopen.close()

with open("OwnerInfoCSV.csv", "r") as inf:
    reading2 = list(csv.reader(inf, skipinitialspace=True))

for sublist in reading2:
    if line1 in sublist:
        print("yay")


print(line1) # This displays "UY34DSF"

print(reading2) # This displays the below list of lists:

[['Name', 'Reg', 'Postcode', 'Address', 'Speed'], ['JohnSmith', 'NR87TYH', 'PE26RE', '1EnglandRoad', '67'], ['JaneSmithe', 'UY34DSF', 'SW147EG', '23SouthDrive', '82'], ['JimmyJones', 'PL20DCH', 'NW33EX', '145EastRidings', '54'], ['VinnyJones', 'TD53BFC', 'NG167YT', '95BirdRoad', '79'], ['ClarkKent', 'FH45NFH', 'SE89YG', '8NorthAvenue', '56']]
```

Comment: your code works for me - it prints the ding dong message. OK you changed the question, don't have time to hit a moving target.

Comment: Works fine, it prints the message. I printed the sublist also, it is working correctly.

Comment: Interesting!  I had a look and I can see that the "numPlate" variable is being read with a lower case "t" in front of the text?  I will google this to see what's up.

Answer (score 2):

This will create a list of all lists that contain the string.

```
matching_lists = [ls for ls in addressList if numPlate in ls]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read e.g. line1, it may have invisible carriage-return or possibly space attached. Check this by e.g. printing the length of line1, or printing something immediately before/after it. Of course these non-visible characters will prevent line1 matching anything in the list. Use strip() to clean it up, e.g.:

```
import string
line1 = string.strip(fopen.readline())
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction but I ended up using 'line1[:-1] ' as the space was the last char in the string.  Thanks!

Comment: Using strip() is more robust because, for example, the next time you edit StandardUKReg.txt you might happen to not put a carriage-return on the end of the reg, and then your solution of simply ignoring the last character would fail again. Strip() will also remove excess spaces.